# In Windows 10, why does unchecking the "Read-only" checkbox here not "stick"?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, filesystems, read-only

This is a long-time issue which I have not noticed for a long time, because I have learned to stay away from thinking that there is any kind of control over the files and their many "modes" and weird complexity.

Basically, I right-click my "music" dir on an internal SSD disk and see that it has this:

```
[X] Read-only (Only applies to files in folder)
```

The "X" looks more like a square, BTW, if that is significant.

Alright, so I don't want any file in that directory tree to be "read only", so I uncheck the box and click "Apply" and then "OK".

Now, if I again right-click the directory and pick "Properties", it will again be checked/filled. It has not respected my choice to make the files "not read only". Or, if it has, it is not reflected by this GUI box.

Is this yet another plain bug in Windows, or is this some bizarre intended behaviour which "makes kinda sense if you know the history"?

Answer (score 2):

The *Read only* property for *folders* is fairly meaningless. It does not make the *contents* of the folder read-only. It is **theoretically** a **tristate indicator** in the *Properties* dialog, *supposedly* showing whether:

- *All* of the contents are read-only [check mark].
- *None* of the contents are read-only [empty].
- *Some* of the contents are read-only, and some not [black square].

But the read-only attribute **as displayed in the *Properties* dialog** is **incorrect**, and has been through many versions of Windows. In the *Explorer Properties* dialog, when first diplayed, it is *always* shown in the indeterminate (black box) state. Checking or unchecking the box does nothing.

[image: Read-only tristate indicator]

The folder *does* have a *read-only* attribute in the NTFS partition, and the attribute *can* be set or unset using the *attrib* command, as shown below, but that has no practical effect on the folder, nor on its contents, and when the folder with *read-only* attribute set is viewed in the *Properties* dialog, it is *still* displayed as indeterminate.

[image: Setting Read-only attribute in CMD]

[image: Read-only is always shown as indeterminate]

*C'est la vie.*

Answer (score 0):

***Yes, the square vs the check is a very significant detail.***

That square represents a "neutral setting" for a folder and is always there by default.  Perhaps not the best design but it is what it is.  If you do this with an actual FILE, you will see the real value.
Also, this will fail on any files that you don't have permissions to change but will offer you the check boxes anyway.

***Why is it there then?***
To allow you to apply attribute changes *in mass* to the files contained within.  For instance, after you check or uncheck the [X] and OK or Apply, it will attempt to apply this file attribute to all of the FILES under it.
You can always go to the command prompt and use the `attrib` command with the `/s` switch to get predictable behavior.

Please see [this link](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/85640-set-unset-read-only-attribute-files-folders-windows-10-a.html) for more information.

Funny.. until you asked the question, I never really thought about it.